# How to validate PHP poll?

Tags: php, mysql

i have made a system where an admin can login and create a poll, the problem is even when no data is entered the poll is still being created, i want to prevent this. I have tried using if(empty but it doesn’t seem to work, any help would be appreciated. I apologies if this is not formatted correctly.

```
<?php include 'functions.php'; $pdo = pdo_connect_mysql(); $msg = '';
// Check if POST data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {
// Post data not empty insert a new record
// Check if POST variable “title” exists, if not default the value to blank, basically the same for all variables
$title = isset($_POST[‘title’]) ? $_POST[‘title’] : ‘’;
$desc = isset($_POST[‘desc’]) ? $_POST[‘desc’] : ‘’;
// Insert new record into the “polls” table
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(‘INSERT INTO polls VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)’);
$stmt->execute([$title, $desc]);
// Below will get the last insert ID, this will be the poll id
$poll_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

// Get the answers and convert the multiline string to an array, so we can add each answer to the "poll_answers" table
$answers = isset($_POST['answers']) ? explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['answers']) : '';
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
   // If the answer is empty there is no need to insert
   if (empty($answer)) {
       echo 'no entry';
   } else {
       echo 'continue';
   }
   // Add answer to the "poll_answers" table
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO poll_answers VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, 0)');
   $stmt->execute([$poll_id, $answer]);
}
// Output message
$msg = 'Created Successfully!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Step one: Use the _proper_ quotes as string delimiter. Right now, you are using “curly” quotes in multiple places there, that is wrong.

Comment: Okay. I will change that.

Comment: Your code contains curly quotes `‘` that will produce parse errors. They need to be changed to regular ones like these `'`. @bob011

Comment: We probably also need to see what the SELECT is for your users being logged in, as well as the HTML / form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_POST))
```

is not sufficient - when you submit the form, the array itself will likely not be empty, even if the fields within it are.

e.g. you might have something like this sent to you as the contents of `$_POST`:

```
array('title'=> '','des'=>'')
```

You need to validate all the specific fields which you require to be populated, and only carry out the insert if they're all completed to your satisfaction. This is a standard validation process.

e.g.

```
if (!empty($_POST["desc"]) && !empty($_POST["title"]))
{
   //run your query here
}
```

Complete sample:

```
<?php 
include 'functions.php'; 
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql(); 
$msg = '';

// Check if POST data is valid
if (!empty($_POST["desc"]) && !empty($_POST["title"]))
  // Post data not empty insert a new record
  // Check if POST variable “title” exists, if not default the value to blank, basically the same for all variables
  $title = $_POST["title"];
  $desc = $_POST["desc"];
  // Insert new record into the “polls” table
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO polls VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->execute([$title, $desc]);
  // Below will get the last insert ID, this will be the poll id
  $poll_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

// Get the answers and convert the multiline string to an array, so we can add each answer to the "poll_answers" table
  $answers = isset($_POST['answers']) ? explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['answers']) : '';

  foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    // If the answer is empty there is no need to insert
    if (empty($answer)) {
      echo 'no entry';
     } else {
      echo 'continue';
    }
    // Add answer to the "poll_answers" table
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO poll_answers VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, 0)');
    $stmt->execute([$poll_id, $answer]);
  }
  // Output message
  $msg = 'Created Successfully!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Okay, i think i understand what you mean, so if (!empty($_POST)) must be removed, and your code needs to be added? thank you for your help

Comment: Yes it would make sense to do that. Try it and see if it helps, and let me know.

Comment: Hello, could you tell me where i need to place your code on the page? in the spot that the !empty($_POST))  was in? or lower down? thank you so much.

Comment: The same place would make sense. Just replace it. P.S. just for future reference please don't edit your question to update the code and remove previous versions - it makes the questions and answers not make sense. If you do change the code per a request from someone in the comments, you should add the second version at the end of your question. I've rolled back your removal of the code because both answers would no longer make sense without that.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that! i will know in future reference!

Comment: Hello! i replaced my code with yours, and got the following result. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'INTO' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\kitbook\registration\create.php on line 12

Comment: I would guess you've misplaced a quote mark somewhere. My code alone wouldn't cause that. I've added a complete sample, for the avoidance of doubt.

Comment: Hello there, okay so i just removed only the if (!empty($_POST)) and replaced it with your code on the same line and unfortunately it still allows the user to vote multiple times.

Comment: @bob011 Where is your SELECT query then? If the answers given still allow users to vote multiple times, then you'll need to make sure that your system is setup to have users be logged in and that the conditions are set and met. Not to mention the way your database is setup. All of those are unknown and important for everyone to know.

Comment: @bob011 _" it still allows the user to vote multiple times."_ ...ok but that has nothing to do with validating whether the fields are completed, and nothing to do with the question you originally asked. I suggest you raise a separate question about that because - as FunkFortyNiner's comment mentions, it's a somewhat wider issue. In fact I'd suggest it probably has nothing to do with the code in this question at all. Meanwhile if this answer has helped you with your current question please mark it accepted and/or upvote it. And then tackle the voting issue separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You to make **form validation** before users send form.

For example, prevent sending empty form or prevent if specific field/fields are empty.

You can achieve this using both html or javascript:

1. Html - tags required property

   ```
   <form action="/action_page.php">
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
     <input type="submit">
   </form>
   ```
2. JS - there are a lot of frameworks (Bootstrap) or You can do it just in jquery

[Bootstrap validation in doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation)

[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XqXNT/)

Comment: This is useful for improved user experience. But it should be noted that server-side validation is always required as well, because the client-side validation can easily by changed or bypassed.

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your code is

```
if (!empty($_POST))
```

above condition will not work as when you submit the form post has array something like below

```
array('title'=> '','des'=>'')
```

So above array is not seems to be empty and then after you have written something like below to get title and description

```
$title = isset($_POST[‘title’]) ? $_POST[‘title’] : ‘’;
$desc = isset($_POST[‘desc’]) ? $_POST[‘desc’] : ‘’;
```

Which will get empty entries if not set. So you need to check for title and desc for empty if its not empty then only you need to insert into database.

You can learn PHP here: http://thecodetutorial.com/

Comment: Hello there, yeah i was unsure would it work, it was just something that i tried as a solution, so i need to check $title and $desc if it is empty? thanks.

Comment: Does this helps or not??

Comment: The code/answer contains curly quotes `‘` that will produce parse errors. They need to be changed to regular ones.

Comment: Best to use `!empty()` over `isset()`. If you want the reason, I'll go find it for you.

Comment: Best use both as if it is not set then it will give you a notice or an error in PHP

Comment: @sanjayrathod that's unnecessary. using !empty() will already cover all the cases that isset() covers. So if you're using !empty() then isset() is redundant. A notice won't be generated as far as I can see from a quick test.

Comment: if you think that it won't generate notice or error. Then you need to learn PHP.

Comment: @sanjayrathod Excuse me? There is no need to make personal comments. As I said, I  have tested it (on a PHP install which normally generates notices) and it definitely does not generate a notice. Here's an example: `if (!empty($_GET["x"]))
{
 echo "not empty";
}
else
{
 echo "empty";
}` will **not** generate a notice (or any other issue). Whereas `echo $_GET["x"];` in the same script will generate one (assuming there is no querystring value called x provided). I don't say these things without testing them first!